# How can I reuse my Nether Reactor?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I built my nether reactor out of a bunch of gold and diamonds I had been storing to see what it does. It was pretty crazy; after I activated it I warped to the netherworld version of my land and was attacked by the zombie pigmen and promptly died (serves me right for activating it unprepared!)

Now I have a giant obsidian tower in my world that seems to serve no purpose. Nothing special spawns inside it regardless of the time of day, it just sits there taking up space. I didn't get to keep anything I scavenged when I entered the nether because I died while in there and my stuff didn't seem to remain when I returned to the reactor location.

So, do I need to rebuild the whole reactor again just to re-enter the nether, or is there a way to re-activate the reactor once it's done its thing already? Is it a one time thing?

Comment: This is only in Minecraft Pocket Edition, no mods present. V0.5.0 On iOS but is (presumably) the same for all OS versions of Minecraft.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad.

Comment: Remember; do not build the nether reactor in your house!! I did. It wasnt fun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This item is single-use I'm afraid, you'll have to build another, there is no way to reactivate it. If the Zombie Pigmen are a problem, change your difficulty to peaceful and they will not spawn (only items will).

Comment: I suspect you may be right. However I choose to keep this question unaccepted for now just in hope that it's not the case. I don't want to start regretting all the badass golden swords I crafted and wasted if I've now mined it all away and can't rebuild the reactor. :(

Comment: this answer isn't entirely correct

Answer (score 5):

Just use a diamond pick to harvest the obsidian blocks sticking up in the center of the structure and find your reactor inside.

Comment: Ok, but the gold is still gone. 36 ingots is pretty hard to come by :(

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is dig the Obsidian. The one where it has the Nether Reactor and dig out the middle one. If you do that you'll get your Nether Reactor back and also before all the block turns red you have chance to dig your Gold Block out.

Comment: Wow, it's quite a small time window to dig out the gold again. Even with a diamond pickaxe I only got one block out before it turned to obsidian. Could probably get two if I was more prepared, but I don't think it's possible to get all four back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - even if you leave (when it is on Peaceful Mode), all of the stuff that comes out of the Nether Reactor will vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Just dig the core out before the reactor while it is still red, and the structor will stay solid. Dig inside, destroy the red reactor, make stairs to that small room at the top and then make a diamond block stash.

Answer (score 0):

If you mine out the gold blocks right after you activate the reactor, the reactor will still activate, but you will get the gold back. There is also the core in the center of a 9x9 block on the bottom floor of the reactor.