# What's a nether reactor?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Minecraft Pocket Edition (the paid version), and noticed that in my crafting table, I could craft something called a 'Nether Reactor'. I could not find anything about it online (or maybe I didn't look close enough). So, my question is, did MOJANG create a new block while I wasn't looking, or is this Pocket Edition specific.

There is [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93180/how-can-i-reuse-my-nether-reactor) question about reusing one, but it doesn't tell what it does. What does it do and how can I use it?

Comment: It's on the [Minecraft wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Nether_Reactor), accessible as one of the top results from a simple [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Nether+Reactor).

Comment: @Yves I wonder how I managed to miss that.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :P

Comment: The reactor itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is NOT a portal. Using a pattern of gold and cobblestone blocks, the reactor builds a 17x17x17 nether cube in which you are trapped while the thing spews out all kinds of resources like ingots, beds, glow stones, and zombie pigmen. The cube then slightly deteriorates and the reaction is over. The core can be used as many times as desired.

Answer (score 2):

It's a single-use Nether Portal replacement. It takes you into the Nether as a replacement for Portals in the pocket edition, but since it can't be used it's much more costly and risky.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern only work in the pocket edition 4 blocks of gold some cobblestone and
1 nether reactor core if you click on it this will trap/teleport you in a builded cube
If you don't follow the pattern it won't take you where you get trapped in

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to build this in creative.

[image: a construction to make a tower appear around you]

- Layer 1: You basically just make a plus sign on the ground made of 5 cobblestone blocks. Place a gold block in each corner (four blocks of gold).
- Layer 2: Place a cobblestone block on top of each gold block (four blocks of cobblestone) and a nether reactor in the middle.
- Layer 3: Finally, make another plus sign out of 5 cobblestone on top of everything, in the middle.

Place a chest nearby (to put everything into) and then change to survival. You might want to set it to peaceful if you don't want to be overloaded with zombie pigmen. Just tap the nether reactor (this only works in SURVIVAL) and a giant netherrack castle will appear around you. There will also be a heap of supplies that will spew out.

Collect these, dig your way out, and put them in your chest. This is one way to get quartz with out going to the nether. The castle will soon get a heap of holes in it. Switch back to creative, fill in the holes, decorate, go back to Survival, so you have a great tower to live in and helpful supplies to use!

Answer (score 0):

It is just a replacement for a nether portal, and in order to activate it, you need other blocks as well. It is a replacement for a nether portal.

Answer (score -1):

It's creates a mini nether when you activate and it was supposed to compensate for not having the actual nether at the time it was made because it would be too laggy for all the old devices.

Comment: Posts should be upvoted based on their value, not based on the user who posted them.